# single PreparedStatement for batch processiong

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, batch-processing

I want to insert record in one table and at the same time I want to update record in another table. for this I want to use transaction if any one of query get failed then all will get rollback. For this I m using batch processing...steps as follows

First I m setting `AutoCommit(false)` to connection obj.

Then `dmlPreparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(Insertquery);`

- setting parameters to `dmlPreparedStatement`
- `dmlPreparedStatement.addBatch();`

after this I want to add `UPDATE` query in batch for this I did-

- `dmlPreparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(Updatequery);` same PreparedStatement object but with new update query
- setting parameters to `dmlPreparedStatement`
- `dmlPreparedStatement.addBatch();`

when `dmlPreparedStatement.executeBatch();` is done it only execute update statement insert operation is not done.

Is their any way to use same PreparedStatement object for multiple diff. queries.

CODE IN TRY BLOCK

```
String query="INSERT INTO CANDIDATEANSWER " +
                "(CANDIDATEEXAMITEMID,FKCANDIDATEID,FKITEMID,OPTIONID,ATTEMPTEDTIME,ISCORRECT) " +
                "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        dbConnection = icrudCandidate.getConnection();
        dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
        dmlPreparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
        for (CandidateAnswer candidateAnswer : candidateItemAssociation.getCandidateAnswers()) {
            if(candidateAnswer.getOptionID() != 0)
            {
                dmlPreparedStatement.setLong(1, candidateAnswer.getCandidateExamItemID());
                dmlPreparedStatement.setLong(2, candidateAnswer.getFkcandidateID());
                dmlPreparedStatement.setLong(3, candidateAnswer.getFkItemID());
                dmlPreparedStatement.setLong(4, candidateAnswer.getOptionID());
                java.util.Date dt =  new java.util.Date();
                dmlPreparedStatement.setObject(5, dt,java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP,java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP);
                String sql = "SELECT ISCORRECT FROM ITEMOPTION IO WHERE IO.OPTIONID="+candidateAnswer.getOptionID();
                preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
                resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery(sql);
                while(resultSet.next())
                {
                    if(resultSet.getBoolean("ISCORRECT"))
                    {
                        dmlPreparedStatement.setBoolean(6, true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isCorrect=false;
                        dmlPreparedStatement.setBoolean(6, false);
                    }
                }
                resultSet.close();
            }
            dmlPreparedStatement.addBatch();
        }
         query="UPDATE CANDIDATEITEMASSOCIATION SET ISCORRECT=?,MARKSOBTAINED=? WHERE CANDIDATEEXAMITEMID="+candidateItemAssociation.getCandidateAnswers().get(0).getCandidateExamItemID();
         PreparedStatement dmlPreparedStatement1 = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
         dmlPreparedStatement1.setBoolean(1, isCorrect);
         if(isCorrect)
         {
             dmlPreparedStatement1.setString(2, String.valueOf(getPerItemMarksByPaperId(paperId)));              
         }
         else
         {               
             dmlPreparedStatement1.setString(2, String.valueOf((getNagetiveMarksPerItemByPaperIdAndEventID(eventID,paperId)*-1)));
         }
         dmlPreparedStatement1.addBatch();

        int[] count = dmlPreparedStatement.executeBatch();
        count = dmlPreparedStatement1.executeBatch();
        dbConnection.commit();
        return true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch processing and transactions are two different things: when using batch you don't get a rollback if something fails in between. 
The main advantage of batches is that it allows you to execute **the same instruction with multiple parameters**.

What you need to do is execute the first insert batch with `dmlPreparedStatement.executeBatch();` before starting to do the update.

When the update batch has been executed you need to commit the transaction with `connection.commit();` or rollback it if something failed.

More info in this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-transaction-example/)

Comment: Thanks, Link is very useful, but with transaction can I user batch processing also?

Comment: Yes, you can use batches or transactions separately or the two at the same time. In your case, you're doing a single insert and a single update so the batch is not useful, a simple statement would do.

Comment: I have updated code above, I m doing multiple insert and only one update. also in between insert I m using SELECT statement to take value of an column from another table.is above code correct?

Comment: Yes, this seems correct except for the (missing) exception handling code. For clarity you should rename dmlPreparedStatement into updateStatement and dmlPreparedStatement1 into updateStatement. Also, your select statement should use parameters instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Yes Thanks for your valuable guidance...catch u later if I face some prob.(?) :)

Answer (score 0):

PreparedStatement object for excuteing same SQL statement for multiple times not multiple SQL
  Statements for multiple times.
Acrroding to [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

> SQL statement is precompiled and stored in a PreparedStatement object, So that you can execute that same pre-compiled SQL statement multiple times with the changes in input parameters that leads to improvement in performance.

Here you are **not changing input parameters, you are changing PreparedStatement object**  
by the statement  `dmlPreparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(Updatequery);`
Then you are calling `executeBatch()` method on the newley created Object.
It means you are going to excute the last pre-compiled query and ingoring previous one.